# Is .Net core 1.0 ready to be used on a full scale production site yet?

Tags: .net, production-environment, asp.net-core-1.0

I like the idea of learning new things and within .Net the new Core 1.0 is as new as its gets as they have just renamed it from .Net 5 to .Net Core 1.0

But the project I was thinking of using it on is not a pet project or a small test this will be a full enterprise solution, in its current state is .Net Core 1.0 is ready to use like this? as it seam's to be missing a few bits and obviously has not been tested or battle hardened like the old .Net.

Now the programmer in me wants to do the new thing, but the work side says to stick with what's safe so you don't overrun.

Comment: The answers are clear themselves. If you do follow Microsoft Build 2016, check the second keynote and hear that some online game already uses ASP.NET Core in their production and achieve great results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE 2017: Both runtime and tooling have reached "RTM", have been released and are supported by Microsoft.

"Release Candidate" versions of .NET Core may have unanticipated bugs but are **supported** and [covered by a "Go Live" license](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/11/18/announcing-asp-net-5-release-candidate-1/). So if you have a problem and a support contract, Microsoft will help you. Also, you can probably expect major blocking issues to be addressed in a timely manner (there has been an "rc1 update1" with a few fixes). The team frequently reiterates that they believe an RC to be production ready and appreciate feedback if you do run into issues (see the videos on [live.asp.net](https://live.asp.net)).

While there is no RC for the rebranded "core 1.0"-version yet, you can start out by using the RC1 (using `dnx` instead of the `dotnet` cli).
The [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) has not yet been updated but a lot of github repos ([cli](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/milestones), [coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/milestones), [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/milestones)) have been updated with an "rc2" milestone for April 22 and an "rtm" for June 30.

According to the "old" schedule, .NET Core and ASP.NET Core would have already shipped ("rtm") but they decided to make infrastructure changes - switching to a new CLI, TFM ("netstandard") and "deployment model" (no `dnx` anymore). In my opinion, seeing that the currently, most work is happening on this infrastructure, you can expect the "core" (pun intended) to be stable and i personally would use it for production systems.

If you are starting development now: the daily builds of `dnx` are still updated to work with the new `dotnet` cli projects so you get Visual Studio Tooling Support.

Answer (score -1):

The roadmap for .NET Core on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md) states the following

> The RC1 [release candidate](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc1) will be a supported and production ready cross-platform release.

The RC is a **Go Live** release meaning it is supported on Windows, OS X and Linux and that you can deploy your app to production and call Microsoft support if you need help.